# MonoDevelop Complete Brace Close

Tags: ide, monodevelop, intellisense

I've started using MonoDevelop again, and one thing driving me nuts is having to complete every brace (my old IDE did it for me).

Is there a way to have MonoDevelop autocomplete brace closures?

E.g. if I type

> if(bool) {

Then it will auto complete the closing brace

> }

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the **Preferences** dialog under **Text Editor** - **Behavior** there is an **Insert matching brace** option.

This auto completes the brace, but it puts it next to the first opening brace so you will have to press return to move it into the location you have in your source code. The auto completion of the brace does not seem to indent the code at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac as answered by @MattWard

On Windows 10 got to **Tools > options > Text Editor - Behaviour** and there is an **Insert Matching Brace** option just enable it

Tested on Mono 5.9.6